# Cast exception after deploying to glassfish

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have deployed my application that runs on weblogic server to glassfish. 
When I try to send data to my service I get internal server error.

It fails here:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionHolder40 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
    at oracle.sql.CLOB.createTemporary(CLOB.java:684)
    at oracle.sql.CLOB.createTemporary(CLOB.java:652)
```

I tried to turn jdbc wrapping off in connection pool settings, but that doesn't help.
What could be wrong?

EDIT:
It seems like it crashes on BLOB.createTemporary as well, but it gets connection. 
On glassfish I have ojdbc6.jar driver, another application that does this as well works however.

Comment: where did you keep your ojdbc6.jar?

Comment: In glassfish domain's library folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now i've resolved this by kind of workaround.

When this exception is thrown i call database procedure that returns empty blob/clob.

In my opinion problem is that connection wrapper from weblogic implements something that wrapper from glassfish does not.

Comment: had same problem, solved in the same way: i managed to create an oracle stored procedure that just returns a clob, and once obtained this, my clob is ready to be filled.